# Bluetooth Example Code for Cocoa (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, bluetooth

I'm looking for example code for setting up a connection to a bluetooth device using the Bluetooth API in Cocoa.  Apple used to include this type of example code in the XCode tools package under the /Developer/Examples/Bluetooth folder, but upon downloading the latest version of XCode (3.2.1), these bluetooth examples have been removed from that directory.

There is now a readme file located at /Developer/Examples/ReadMe.rtf that explains that all example code is on the ADC website.  However, it seems that the ADC website does NOT include bluetooth sample code.

I've tried googling, but I can't seem to find any good examples for how to get bluetooth going on Mac OS X with Cocoa.  Can anybody help me out?  I wish I had copied those examples to a backup location before updating to XCode 3.2.1!  Curses, Apple! Why have you taken them from me?

Comment: It looks to me like there are some examples here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html?filter=bluetooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what I've done: download an old copy of XCode and use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract what you need.

Comment: Thanks! This was the quickest way to get the example code I wanted.  The older version of the tools (3.1.4) are on the developer website, and Pacifist is a great little app for extracting just the parts I needed.

Answer (score 37):

I recently went through my backups to look at this code and have posted it in case anyone wants to look at it.

http://cs.dal.ca/~mcormier/Bluetooth.zip

Please note that if you plan on working with Bluetooth for iOS devices then you want to use the Game Kit Peer-to-Peer Connectivity API and not this code.

Comment: And you're still hosting it after two years! Thanks!

Comment: Haha, doesn't take much space. ;)

Comment: Wow, precisely what I was looking for. Spending 5min with your code helped me more than an hour with the Mac Developer Library. Thanks also for the hint with GameKit :)

Comment: The only samples on Mac Developer are Bluetooth Low Energy (Bluetooth Smart).  Excellent example!  Works great on OSX 10.9.5 with XCode 5.1.1.  The Serial Port Profile and OBEX examples were exactly what I needed!

Comment: I need to make a bluetooth service that is discoverable on the mac and can be discovered on a phone. None of these examples work. Is there any other example available? I tried `RFCOMMServerSample`

Answer (score 4):

Let Apple know you need these by filing a bug report (enhancement request) at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Done - problem number 7451594

Answer (score 0):

This (http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1) shows the GameKit bluetooth to connect with ipads, iphones and ipods I believe. I got the code to work and run but couldn't connect with another device whoose bluetooth was on but only my phone was running the application built with this code. So maybe both need to run it? Anyways, hope it helps a bit, I'm also researching a better tutorial where I can actually connect to bluetooth devices and not just ipad, iphone or ipods. If I write something that works, i'll make sure to blog about it here: [blog](http://www.kanersan.com/blog.php).