# Using Bluetooth on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, bluetooth, nxt

I want to make an app that controls the NXT 2.0 over Bluetooth with my MacBook Pro/iMac.

However, I can't find a tutorial on how to use Bluetooth in Xcode for Mac OS X, only for the iPhone.

So, is there a tutorial on using Bluetooth in Xcode for Mac OS X? Would you have an Xcode project to share?

Comment: Maybe this would help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605081/bluetooth-example-code-for-cocoa-objective-c