# Serial Port Profile (SPP) communication on Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth, serial-port, spp

I am looking for **Bluetooth SPP** communication between **MAC OSX** and bluetooth device.
I am able to discover bluetooth device. I could not find examples on **SPP communication** on **Mac OSX**.

I have the foll0wing resources with me

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/bluetooth/Bluetooth.pdf

Could someone point me the examples or any pointers where I can start.

Is it advisable to use SPP. I did not find much info on this but I found some APIs for OBEX?
If we have to use SPP then where can I find links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following links useful

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html?filter=bluetooth

[Bluetooth Example Code for Cocoa (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605081/bluetooth-example-code-for-cocoa-objective-c)

Examples hosted at the following link

http://cs.dal.ca/~mcormier/Bluetooth.zip